# How to use ssh as a xsession

Tags: ssh, window-manager, desktop, kubuntu

I have two computers running Kubuntu 18.04.

From the client, I connect to the server with ssh, all is going well:

```
ssh -X $SERVER_IP 'export $(dbus-launch); plasmashell'
```

I'm able to interact with the desktop as if I was on the server.

But the problem is that I have two plasma shell at the same time, the client's and the server's.

So I tried to create an `xsession` `.desktop` file to launch `ssh` instead of `kde` on the client.

Without success.

I'm able to launch a graphical program (like `xterm`) in which I launch `ssh` but in that case, I have no window manager, so I can't close the windows I open.

So my question is:

**How to construct a `/usr/share/xsession/remote.desktop` file that would be able to:**

- **launch the kde WM: `/usr/bin/kwin`**
- **launch a SSH session: `/usr/bin/ssh -X .....`**

Note: I perform all my test on virtualbox computers.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two step:

1. Create a script that will launch `kwin` and `ssh`
2. Create the *ad-hoc* xsession file

#### 1. Create a /usr/bin/startssh file:

```
kwin&
ssh -X $SERVER_IP 'export $(dbus-launch); plasmashell; exit'
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/startssh
```

#### 2. Create a /usr/share/xsession/remote.desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=XSession
Exec=/usr/bin/startssh
TryExec=/usr/bin/startssh
DesktopNames=Remote ssh
Name=remote-ssh
X-KDE-PluginInfo-Version=5.12.7 # line dumbly copied from plasma.desktop file
```

#### 3. Restart the display manager

```
sudo systemctl restart sddm.service
```

---

Next step: find a clean way to terminate the ssh session, but it will be for another question